# How do I add a SwitchBar in my app?

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to use a SwitchBar from the Android Settings app in my app but after adding it to my activity and adding in all the required parts to get it to compile, I get this compilation error: `Error inflating class com.android.settings.widget.SwitchBar`.

Here are the changes I made to get it to compile:

Added this to my attrs.xml

```
<attr name="switchBarTheme" format="reference" />
<attr name="switchBarMarginStart" format="dimension" />
<attr name="switchBarMarginEnd" format="dimension" />
```

Added this to my dimens.xml

```
<!-- SwitchBar margin start / end -->
<dimen name="switchbar_margin_start">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="switchbar_margin_end">16dp</dimen>
```

Added this to my styles.xml

```
<style name="switchBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material">
    <item name="switchBarMarginStart">@dimen/switchbar_margin_start</item>
    <item name="switchBarMarginEnd">@dimen/switchbar_margin_end</item>
</style>
```

Added this to my Activity.xml

```
<com.android.settings.widget.SwitchBar 
    android:id="@+id/switch_bar"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/switchbar_background"
    android:theme="?attr/switchBarTheme"
    />
```

If this isn't a good way of adding a SwitchBar, how can I exactly replicate the SwitchBar in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Your attributes already defined in SwitchBar.java in settings.This file involve marginend and other properities.And also switch_bar id.Please check this java file and later you can use in this file keys and attributes or you can define different name from there.